# 2 y-axes Dumbbell ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-axes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqDLd.jpg)I am quite new to R and programming in general. So please forgive my ignorance, I am trying to learn.

I have two sets of data and I would like to plot them against each other. Both have 27 rows and 3 columns; one set is called "range" and the other is called "rangePx".
Column “Comp” has the different components, column “Min” is the minimum concentration in % and column “Max” is the maximum concentration in %.

I want to make a 2-y axis dumbbell plot, with the y axis being the different components and x axis being the concentration.

I do manage to create 1 y axis dumbbell plot, but I have troubles to add the second y axis.

Here is a snap from the "range" data

```
 head(range)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Comp         Min    Max
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Methane   0.0100 100   
2 Ethane    0.0100  65.0 
3 Ethene    0.100   20.0 
4 Propane   0.0100  40.0 
5 Propene   0.100    6.00
6 Propadien 0.0500   2.00
```

and here is a snap from the "rangePx" data

```
head(rangePx)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Comp           Min    Max
  <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Methane   50.0     100   
2 Ethane     0.00800  14.0 
3 Ethene     0         0   
4 Propane    0.00800   8.00
5 Propene    0         0   
6 Propadien  0         0
```

Here is the piece of code that I use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(readxl)

theme_set(theme_classic())

range <- read_excel(range.xlsx)
rangePx <- read_excel(rangePx.xlsx")

p <- ggplot(range, aes(x=Max, xend=Min, y = Comp, group=Comp))
p <- p + geom_dumbbell(color="blue")
p
px <- ggplot(rangePx, aes(x=Max, xend=Min, y = Comp, group=Comp))
px <- px + geom_dumbbell(color="green")
p <- p + geom_dumbbell(aes(y=px, color="red"))
p
```

and here is the complain I get when I call `p`:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (27): y, colour, x, xend, group
```

Here I saw a 6x3 data frame but my original data are 27x3

can anyone help me?

Thnx in advance

Comment: using facets is a more ggplot-ish strategy to show data on different scales http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Thanks Nate, but I am not sure I understood your comment. The scales are not different, they all are from 0 to 100. I need to show my plot to a non R audience. A secondary y axis  would make the plot quite straightforward to them.

Comment: the last line `p <- p + geom_dumbbell(aes(y=px, color="red"))` makes no sense as `px` is a geom object not a column of data.

Comment: FWIW `scale_y_continuous()` has a `sec.axis` parameter. Also: `dput(head(…))` output is far more useful than `head()` output (as the SO R FAQ states).

Comment: [SO R FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why do you need secondary y-axis if `Comp` in `range` and `rangePx` are exactly the same?

Comment: @PoGibas this is because I want to compare them in the same plot...

Comment: @StephenHenderson thanks for your comment. Do you mean to replace y=px with y=rangePx?

Comment: Why not to use different color, different shape of points or something else?

Comment: @PoGibas it can be a solution and I will give it a shot. But sooner or later I will face this problem again and I would like to know the answer; not to mention the time I have invested so far :)

Comment: I'm more than happy to help, but I can't image how those double y-axis would look with categorical data. Can you post a drawing?

Comment: @PoGibas thanks, I have prepared a hand drawing, how can I send it to you?

Comment: Just add it to the question

Comment: @PoGibas It really struggles to upload the picture... My picture is 1.5 MB and the limit is 2 MB... Is it any other way to send it to you?

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` does not have the ability to plot 2 y-axes - this is an intentional decision by Hadley Wickham who wrote the package. You can see his response to a similar question here where he comments on his reasons for not including:

[Plot with 2 y axes, one y axis on the left, and another y axis on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right)

As mentioned in the comments and in reply to the question, if you want to use `ggplot2` you have to use faceting to compare. Otherwise you need to use a different plotting package.

Comment: Answer is wrong, see [this](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html) and [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/4825054da690c181bbdfe733127b52d8c78c0488/R/axis-secondary.R)

Comment: Answer is out of date, since version 2 2.2.0 it has been possible to add a secondary axis.